# Java program to call other binary with argument. Argument has double quotes in it. Need to work on windows and linux both

Tags: java

I have a java program and from java program I need to call other C binary.

This C binary takes db query as an argument.

Now I have a situation where my db query itself contains double quotes within it.
Example : java program is sample.java, c binary is test.exe
query = select * from emp where name="abc"

Java program uses execute method of ProcessBuilder to call exe with argument.

When I execute my java program on Windows, I need to explicitly convert " to \" in query before calling exe. So that when exe reads that argument it will take proper argument as mentioned in example.

If I do not explicitly convert " to \", exe will take query till select * from emp where name= It will end when it finds first double quote.

Now when I run same java program on Linux and explicitly convert " to \" in query, the binary on linux reads this argument but then it retains \ in the query. So it takes query as Select * from emp where name=\"abc\" Because of this it doesnt execute query properly.

So I end up having platform specific code in my java class. It converts " to \" if program runs on windows else it does not.

What I am looking for is any unified way to do this without making platform specific checks in java.

Thanks,
Jenish

Comment: My first question is why you wouldn't directly connect to the database server using [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and the appropriate database driver.

Comment: And the second question is how are you using `ProcessBuilder` in such a broken way that it isn't escaping things for you?

Comment: @Powerlord We are not executing query on DB, the exe parses this query to run on internal datastructure

Comment: @Boris ProcessBuilder would have done the trick but the problem is here the argument passed are also read by exe so if we dont add \ explicitly exe doesnt read till first double quotes only on windows